# How to modify duplicate strings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, truncate

I'm dealing with truncating a column of string values in a table from 15 characters to 10 characters (this is the new max length I want to permit for the column).

There is a unique key on a pair of columns in the table, this one being one of them.

Because of the truncation, there is a possibility that this could be violated.

For example:

```
| ID |        C1       | C2 |
| -- | --------------- | -- |
| 1  | 123456789012345 |  1 |
| 2  | 123456789012346 |  1 |
| 3  | 123456789012345 |  2 |
| 4  | 123456789012346 |  2 |
```

Let's say I have a unique key on C1 and C2. C1 is currently varchar(15), but for reasons that are beyond my control, it's being changed to varchar(10).

I have to truncate the values in C1 to strings of length 10. But if I just do so mindlessly, I'll obviously end up (in the example above) violating the unique key constraint.

So, I know how to find all the duplicates using something like:

```
select
    t1.ID,
    LEFT(t1.C1, 10) as C1,
    t1.C2
INTO
    #ColumnDuplicates
FROM
    t t1
    join t t2 on
        t1.ID <> t2.ID
        AND LEFT(t1.C1, 10) = LEFT(t2.C1, 10)
WHERE
    t1.C2 = t2.C2

SELECT * FROM #ColumnDuplicates
```

Referring to the table above, this query would get me:

```
| ID |     C1     | C2 |
| -- | ---------- | -- |
| 1  | 1234567890 |  1 |
| 2  | 1234567890 |  1 |
| 3  | 1234567890 |  2 |
| 4  | 1234567890 |  2 |
```

Now here's where I'm not sure how to do the next step. What I need to do is somehow get to this:

```
| ID |     C1     | C2 |
| -- | ---------- | -- |
| 1  | 123456_001 |  1 |
| 2  | 123456_002 |  1 |
| 3  | 123456_001 |  2 |
| 4  | 123456_002 |  2 |
```

Effectively, I want to find all the duplicate C1 values for each C2 value, and then change the last 4 characters to a *_[0-9][0-9][0-9]* pattern, and progressively number those duplicates from 000 (or 001, I don't really care which is used as the starting point) through to a maximum of 999. This will give me space to deal with around 999 duplicates per C2 value, which I am quite sure based on my familiarity with the data I'm working with will not be an issue.

And then I can easily just use this temporary table to update the C1 values in the main table I am modifying.

My knowledge of SQL at the moment is quite basic, so I don't really know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, you can look at duplicates in the first six characters.  I say lucky, because this assumes you never have more than 1000 such duplicates:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(c1, 6), c2 order by c2) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by left(c1, 6), c2) as cnt
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set c1 = (case when cnt > 1
                   then concat(left(c1, 6), '_', format(seqnum, '000'))
                   else left(c1, 10)
              end);
```

The above is a little pessimistic with respect to duplicates.  It probably makes sense to filter out known singletons before using `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(c1, 6), c2,
                                             (case when cnt10 > 1 then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by c2
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by left(c1, 6), c2,
                                         (case when cnt10 > 1 then 1 else 2 end)
                           ) as cnt6
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by left(c1, 10), c2) as cnt10
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set c1 = (case when cnt10 > 1
                   then concat(left(c1, 6), '_', format(seqnum, '000'))
                   else left(c1, 10)
              end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int NOT NULL,
                            C1 varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                            C2 int NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable (C1,C2);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID, C1, C2)
VALUES (1,'123456789012345',1),
       (2,'123456789012346',1),
       (3,'123456789012345',2),
       (4,'123456789012346',2);
GO

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT C1,
           LEFT(YT.C1,6) + '_' + RIGHT(CONCAT('000',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YT.C1, YT.C2 ASC)),3) AS NewC1
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
    WHERE LEN(YT.C1) > 10) --Unsure if that WHERE is needed
UPDATE CTE
SET C1 = NewC1;
GO

DROP INDEX YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable; --Has to be dropped to alter

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN C1 varchar(10) NOT NULL;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable (C1,C2); --Recreate

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```